# How do you fix a Thread Join() that is stuck

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multi-threading and I am simply getting hands on practice by trying to print a 14000 size String Arraylist using threads. I am not considering efficiency nor even usefulness for that matter; I just want to understand the threading concept.

My output has been extremely faulty and I have tried all kinds of synchronizes and other failed attempts. I came across a tool called join at the moment, however my program doesn't exit and stays running. I debugged the code and the program simply gets stuck on the first thread join and I can't think of any reason or solution to remedy the problem.

The way I approached the problem is by creating 4 threads to split the task of the printing.Then I would wait until all threads were complete and use the join right before closing the output file.

```
public class Threadprinting implements Runnable{
private static List<String> list;
private Thread T1,T2,T3,T4;
public void printinput(List<String> store){
    list=new ArrayList<String>(store);
    Threadprinting threadprinting=new Threadprinting();
    Threadprinting.generatethreads();   
}

public void generatethreads() {
    T1=new Thread(this,"t1");
    T1.start();
    T2=new Thread(this,"t2");
    T2.start();
    T3=new Thread(this,"t3");
    T3.start();
    T4=new Thread(this,"t4");
    T4.start();
}

public void run(){
    try {               
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Output.txt"));
        switch (Thread.currentThread().getName()) {
            case "t1":
                System.out.println("Thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running");
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size() / 4; i++) {
                    out.println((list.get(i)));
                }
                break;
            case "t2":
                System.out.println("Thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running");
                for (int i = list.size() / 4; i < list.size() / 2; i++) {
                    out.println((list.get(i)));
                }
                break;
            case "t3": 
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is running");
                for (int i = list.size()/2; i < list.size()/4+list.size()/2; i++) {
                    out.println((list.get(i)));
                }
                break;
            case "t4": 
                System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is running");
                for (int i = list.size()/4+list.size()/2; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    out.println((list.get(i)));
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("filler");
                break;
            }
            jointhreads();
            out.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("problem came from here");
    }
}
```

Specifically:

```
private void jointhreads() {
    try {
        T1.join();
        T2.join();
        T3.join();
        T4.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("the joins failed");
    }
}
```

}

The program fails to terminate and stays running at T1.join according to the debugger.

Comment: You are in T1 and you do a T1.join(), is that your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are invoking `jointhreads` inside thread you want to join, so
`T1` is basicly waiting for `T1` (itself)  to terminate but that will never happen.

You should invoke `jointrheads` in your main thread, so the application will wait until all worker threads will finish their job

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I understand the problem but how do I go about joining the threads from the main thread while still holding off all threads prior to the out.close() statement.

Comment: You are creating 4 differend Writers (your case is generally bad written) so every thread can close owned stream writer.
You should rather create one output in your main, run workers that will use that output, and than close it in main. Another thing is that writing to stream is not thread safe and you should synchronize this process, but that is annother issue.

Comment: Yes after playing around for a while that is exactly what I did. However I ran into another problem of how to make the threads execute the printing in order from thread 1 to 4. I tried setting priorities but it isn't a reliable solution. But after doing some research I don't think it's really possible to have threads follow a rigid order.

Comment: You cannot guarantee order of execution of parallel threads, that is just in specifiaction of JVM, unless you apply some fancy (and reduntant) logic. But, if you want to print things in serial, than there is no sens to use threads ;]

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
T1.join();
```

means : "the **current thread** must wait until T1 terminates". Your problem is that the **current thread** is T1.

So, it's kind of *I suspend my run until I reach the end*.  (i.e. deadlock)